# CF Component Doesn't Reset Variables

Tags: coldfusion, modal-dialog, cfml

I have some forms and there is a table with "instructions" for each question, for each form. I am trying to add a button which pops a modal displaying each question's instruction. The problem is every button links to the instruction for the first question. The later instructions exist - If I start w/question 2, everything after that shows Q2's instruction. It's as if it gets locked onto the first field and can't discard it.

Here is the component code:

```
<cfcomponent displayname="QxQ" output="false" hint="Gets QxQ information for display on data entry screen">

<cfparam name="qxq_instruct" default="">
<cfparam name="qxq_fieldGUID" default="">

<cffunction name="getFieldInstructions" hint="Gets the QxQ Instructions for the requesting field">

    <cfargument name="qxq_versionGUID" type="string" required="yes">

    <cfargument name="qxq_fieldName" type="string" required="yes">

    <!--- Get FieldGUID based on form VersionGUID and field name --->
    <cfquery name="qryGetqxqfieldGUID" datasource="#application.DSN#">
        SELECT
            FieldGUID
        FROM
            _sysformFields
        WHERE
            VersionGUID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#qxq_versionGUID#">
        AND
            FieldName = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#qxq_fieldName#">
    </cfquery>


    <cfset qxq_fieldGUID = #qryGetqxqfieldGUID.FieldGUID#>

    <!--- Get instructions based on fieldGUID --->
    <cfquery name="qryGetFieldInstructions" datasource="#application.DSN#">
        SELECT
            instruct
        FROM
            _sysFormFieldInstructions
        WHERE
           fieldGUID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#qxq_fieldGUID#">
    </cfquery>

    <cfif qryGetFieldInstructions.recordcount eq 1>
        <cfset qxq_instruct = #qryGetFieldInstructions.instruct#>
    </cfif>

    <cfset modalButton = '
        <!--- Modal Button --->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-small" style="background-color: transparent; border: none" data-toggle="modal" data-target="##exampleModal">
            <i class="fa fa-question-circle-o fa-2x" style="color: ##8a0d25"></i>
        </button>

        <!--- Modal --->
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <span style="text-align: left">
                            #qxq_versionGUID#<br>
                            #qxq_fieldName#<br>
                            #qxq_fieldGUID#<br><br>

                            #qxq_instruct#
                        </span>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    '>

    <cfreturn modalButton>

</cffunction>
```

And here is how I am trying to implement it. This is 2 questions, and should display the instructions for each question. Instead, both buttons display the information for Q1.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">1.</label>
  <label for="oftndrink" class="col-sm-10 control-label" style="text-align:left">
    How often do you have a drink containing alcohol?
  </label>
  <br>
  <cfset form.qxq=createobject("component","#application.componentspath#.cfc_QxQ")>
  <label class="col-sm-1">
        #form.qxq.getFieldInstructions(qxq_versionGUID="#formInfo.versionGUID#",qxq_fieldName="oftndrink")#
  </label>
</div>
```

(Q2)

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">2.</label>
  <label for="numdrinks" class="col-sm-10 control-label" style="text-align:left">
    How many drinks containing alcohol do you have on a typical day when you are drinking?
  </label>
  <br>
  <cfset form.qxq=createobject("component","#application.componentspath#.cfc_QxQ")>
  <label class="col-sm-1">
        #form.qxq.getFieldInstructions(qxq_versionGUID="#formInfo.versionGUID#",qxq_fieldName="numdrinks")#
  </label>
</div>
```

Thanks for pointing out the answer, which turned out to be really easy!
I am now initializing the component in a pre-process that runs once:

```
<cfset form.qxq=createobject("component","#application.componentspath#.cfc_QxQ")>
```

And can add the modal with the correct instructions by inserting just one line. (This part is a big deal because I have to add it to every question on about 150 forms)

```
<span style="text-align: left">#form.qxq.getFieldInstructions(qxq_versionGUID="#formInfo.versionGUID#",qxq_fieldName="varName")#</span>
```

Comment: Nothing to do with the issue, but it doesn't seem like it's really necessary to create new instances of the component each time. Also, cfc functions should always localize any function local variables to avoid potential threading problems.

Comment: Is this also Bootstrap?

Comment: Yes it is bootstrap

I figured it wasn't necessary to re-create it every time, that was one of my attempted fixes. Fortunately was able to get rid of it.

Comment: Good.  Don't forget to VAR scope all function local variables as well, including any query names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that both modals are created with the same ID `exampleModal`.

So, when you try to open using `#exampleModal` it will open the first element in the document. What you need to do is to make the modals have different ID. Something like this.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal#qxq_fieldGUID#">
```

and the button arguments like `data-target="##exampleModal#qxq_fieldGUID#"`.

That being said creating this much html for each question will increase your page size and in the cases where there are a lot of questions that might even crash the browser. You should try to make the modal dynamic by using AJAX or JS Objects containing the instructions.